# debug_and_release option didn't work for linux

Tags: linux, qt, qmake

I'm trying to build my qt-plugin in both debug and release modes under Linux OS (Ubuntu 13.10), but it seems to me qmake ignores **CONFIG += debug_and_release** option. I also tried to use **CONFIG += build_all**, but it didn't work to. When I use the same options on Windows Qt generated two output files (for example *plugin.a* and *plugind.a*), but on Linux i get just one of them. When I force QtCreator to build my project in opposite mode (debug instead of relesae) it overrides already generated target file with the one that has the same name. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you try to call `make debug` and `make release`?

Comment: No, I didn't, I just tried to configure my .pro file

Comment: I think, if you try it after invoking `qmake`, you will get both debug and release builds.

Comment: No, unfortunatelly. I used the same configuration on Windows and get both debug and release output, but not on Linux

Comment: Please add `message($${CONFIG})` at the end of your .pro file, run qmake then copy the output of message() here so that we can see the contents of your CONFIG variable.

Comment: Here it is: `Project MESSAGE: lex yacc warn_on debug uic resources qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index shared def_files_disabled exceptions no_mocdepend release stl qt_no_framework plugin static build_all`

Comment: @MikhailZimka I see `release` twice, `debug` once but I can not see any `debug_and_release`. qmake does not 'ignore' `debug_and_release`, it simply does not find it among the values of variable CONFIG!

Comment: @Bill that was a message for `build_all` option, here is the one for `debug_and_release`: `Project MESSAGE: lex yacc warn_on debug uic resources qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index shared def_files_disabled exceptions no_mocdepend release stl qt_no_framework unix release ReleaseBuild Release build_pass plugin static debug_and_release`. Result is the same

Comment: @MikhailZimka In this case CONFIG is correct. Please edit your question and tell us what is exactly that does not work. What do you expect and what you get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that in your .pro file you should have set different target directories or different target file names. I do not know why but it looks like on Windows the target file names generated into your Makefiles are different and on Linux they are not different. You can try to change either your target directory or your target file name for debug build.
Try either

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    TARGET = plugin
} else {
    TARGET = plugind
}
```

or

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = release
    OBJECTS_DIR = release/.obj
    MOC_DIR = release/.moc
    RCC_DIR = release/.rcc
    UI_DIR = release/.ui
} else {
    DESTDIR = debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = debug/.obj
    MOC_DIR = debug/.moc
    RCC_DIR = debug/.rcc
    UI_DIR = debug/.ui
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunatelly, that doesn't solve my problem. I really have 2 OBJECTS_DIR / MOC_DIR / RCC_DIR (one for debug and one for release buildings), but ony one target file is generated.

Comment: @MikhailZimka Have you added both `debug_and_release` and `build_all` to `CONFIG` at the same time? If I add only `debug_and_release` then `make` builds the project only in release mode. But if I add `debug_and_release` and `build_all` then `make` builds my tiny sample project first in `release` then in `debug` mode and both targets are generated.